# Quad Nics work ONE at a time

Tags: 14.04, networking

Quad nics are not working completely. But there is no error on syslog to trace what's going.

#### lspci | grep Ethernet

```
05:04.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21142/43 (rev 41)
05:05.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21142/43 (rev 41)
05:06.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21142/43 (rev 41)
05:07.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21142/43 (rev 41)
06:04.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21142/43 (rev 41)
06:05.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21142/43 (rev 41)
06:06.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21142/43 (rev 41)
06:07.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21142/43 (rev 41)
07:04.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21142/43 (rev 41)
07:05.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21142/43 (rev 41)
07:06.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21142/43 (rev 41)
07:07.0 Ethernet controller: Digital Equipment Corporation DECchip 21142/43 (rev 41)
```

Only 4 ports are connected for testing

The result of running `lshw -C network | egrep 'logical|irq'`

```
PCI (sysfs)  

   logical name: eth3
   resources: irq:20 ioport:b080(size=128) memory:f7601000-f76013ff memory:f7540000-f757ffff
   logical name: eth6
   resources: irq:20 ioport:a100(size=128) memory:f7402000-f74023ff memory:f7380000-f73bffff
   logical name: eth10
   resources: irq:19 ioport:9100(size=128) memory:f7202000-f72023ff memory:f7180000-f71bffff
   logical name: eth12
   resources: irq:16 ioport:9000(size=128) memory:f7200000-f72003ff memory:f7100000-f713ffff
```

And the result of running `ifconfig | egrep 'eth|inet'` is as following:

```
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:80:c8:b9:86:f7  
          inet addr:192.168.99.101  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth6      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:80:c8:ca:73:36  
          inet addr:192.168.99.102  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth10     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:80:c8:b9:90:be  
          inet addr:192.168.99.104  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth12     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:80:c8:b9:90:c0  
          inet addr:192.168.99.103  Bcast:192.168.99.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

When `eth3` works then rest of all stop working and if I unplug/plug that port will work again.

Please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to install arptables

```
sudo su
apt-get install arptables
```

Arptables is used to set up, maintain, and inspect the tables of ARP rules in the Linux kernel.

It is analogous to iptables, but operates at the ARP layer rather than the IP layer.

Example:

```
sudo su
arptables -F INPUT
arptables -A INPUT -i eth3 --destination-ip ! 192.168.99.101 -j DROP
arptables -A INPUT -i eth6 --destination-ip ! 192.168.99.102 -j DROP
arptables -A INPUT -i eth10 --destination-ip ! 192.168.99.104 -j DROP
arptables -A INPUT -i eth12 --destination-ip ! 1192.1168.99.103 -j DROP
```

This will prevent broadcasts from going into the wrong interface.